# "bold" vs. "bolder" in light of boldface headers

Tags: feature-request, formatting

I noticed that headers use bold which makes the use of <strong> in headers invisible. Changing the style of <strong> (and <b>) to "bolder" *might* be appropriate.

Perhaps there is a reason that increasing font weight in headers is undesirable, but I am *guessing* that the issue has not arisen because headers are rare and adding strong emphasis is rare (and the two might even be negatively correlated).

For an example of where "bolder" is not unreasonable, see the "Sometimes strong emphasis (bold) is appropriate." header in [this post](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/697).

Comment: Devs, this question is clearly at the network-wide level - is it OK here, or should it be migrated to MSO?

Comment: @Standback, move it to MSO. I guess it will be closed there, but well ... Honestly I do not comprehend this question. Just let me make clear that in most browsers "strong" is rendered like "bold", but they are two different things. Same like "italic" and "emphasis".

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for here, you can distinctly see emphasis in a header (as he showed in the post you linked), you want selective bold in them, with the same varying font size depending on which header was used?

Comment: @TimPost Both 'h3' (the header) and 'strong' use "bold" styling, so a section with 'strong' emphasis *within* a header is **not** in fact emphasized relative to the other text of the header. Perhaps the fonts do not support any weight other than normal and bold, in which case using "bolder" for 'strong' would be meaningless as would using something like "font-weight:700" for headers and "font-weight:900" for 'strong'. Is that sufficient clarification?